# Simple method of client javascript communicating with server node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My objective is to design a small site with auto-completion of a field which would take suggestions from server's database (Node.js + MySQL).

What methods I could use to achieve this client-server communication as user types value into a field. I am looking for something greater than writing own AJAX requests, but easier than frameworks like Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the same NodeJS + MySQL setup.

If you already have your app going, I suggest installing `socket.io`. Otherwise, look into `Express.IO` which is a framework for NodeJS development with Socket.IO integrated into it.

Websockets make AJAX look silly!

In NodeJS, you listen for `io.emit("someEvent", {object-data-here});` on the client side, and route it on the server side with `app.io.route("someEvent", function(request,response) {});`

Don't copy and paste this, but firing a socket for a `keyUp` event is easy peasy.

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputfield");
input.addEventListener("keyUp", function() {
    io.emit("aKeyWasPressed", {value:this.value}); //on key up, send input value to Node
}, false); //false for bubbling event
```

Comment: +1 for alternate solution but be cautious that dealing with websockets means more users having problems due to proxy/firewalls (and socket.io doesn't work well enough to circumvent proxy limitations). I *do* use autocompletion using socket.io but only when my app already use websockets.

Comment: @dystroy Yes, I have noticed socket.io not working behind a corporate firewall. Good news, is they are not my target audience. And in addition, I will learn a little bit more of socket.io.  Thank you for the detailed answer, I am already using Express, thanks for mentioning Express.IO

Answer (score 2):

take a look at jQuery $.ajax() method. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can use the jquery-ui autocomplete for your autocomplete functionality. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/